# how to extract data from a JSON response

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter, curl

I have an AJAX request to display a list of addresses from the users postcode. It will display them in a dropdown list for the user to select. I have shown the PHP, JS ans repsonse below.

I have the JSON response using cURL. I am using CI and jQuery.

How do i extract the data I need from the response and place them into a HTML options tags.
The ID will go in the option value tag and the description will go between the opening and closing option tags.

Here is my JS:

```
$.get(
    '<?=site_url('api/postcode') ?>',
    {
        'postcode' : postcode
    },
    function(data) {

        $( '#loader-address' ).hide();

        // Show the dropdown list           
        var list = '<option value="">Choose...</option>';

        // Create address options from JSON

    },
    'json'
);
```

Here is my PHP function:

```
public function get_by_postcode( $postcode )
{
    /* Build up the URL to send the request to. */
    $sURL = "http://services.Postcodeanywhere.co.uk/json.aspx?";
    $sURL .= "account_code=" . urlencode($this->pca->account);
    $sURL .= "&license_code=" . urlencode($this->pca->license);
    $sURL .= "&action=lookup";
    $sURL .= "&type=by_Postcode";
    $sURL .= "&postcode=" . urlencode($postcode);


    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$sURL);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
    $ContentsFetch = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $ContentsFetch;
}
```

Here is the JSON respone:

```
"[{\"id\":\"5378660.00\",\"seq\":\"0\",\"description\":\"1 Carrington Close Croydon\"},\r\n{\"id\":\"5378661.00\",\"seq\":\"1\",\"description\":\"2 Carrington Close Croydon\"},\r\n{\"id\":\"5378662.00\",\"seq\":\"2\",\"description\":\"3 Carrington Close Croydon\"},\r\n{\"id\":\"5378663.00\",\"seq\":\"3\",\"description\":\"4 Carrington Close Croydon\"},\r\n{\"id\":\"5378664.00\",\"seq\":\"4\",\"description\":\"5 Carrington Close Croydon\"},\r\n{\"id\":\"5378665.00\",\"seq\":\"5\",\"description\":\"6 Carrington Close Croydon\"},\r\n{\"id\":\"5378666.00\",\"seq\":\"6\",\"description\":\"7 Carrington Close Croydon\"},\r\n{\"id\":\"5378667.00\",\"seq\":\"7\",\"description\":\"8 Carrington Close Croydon\"}]\r\n"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getJSON` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

```
$.getJSON(url, param ,function(data) { //url - return json page

  $( '#loader-address' ).hide();

   var list = '<option value="">Choose...</option>';
   $.each(data, function() {
       list += '<option value="'+this.id+'">'+this.description+'</option>';
   });
};
```

And your json response in javascript must be `"[{"id":"5378660.00","seq":"0","description":....`. Escape quote need not

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data.id` in your javascript. Combine with the jQuery `$.each()` function to iterate over the data. Like so:

```
$.get(
    '<?=site_url('api/postcode') ?>',
    {
        'postcode' : postcode
    },
    function(data) {

        $( '#loader-address' ).hide();

        // Show the dropdown list           
        var list = '<option value="">Choose...</option>';
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            list += '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.description+'</option>';
        });

        // Create address options from JSON

    },
    'json'
);
```